# Unable to free a pointer outside a loop in C?

Tags: c, file, memory, struct, malloc

HI I tried to read some data from a input file and construct them to a struct called packet and write it to my output file.The program itself works fine in terms of getting the correct output. However, while running the program with "valgrind" to check memory leaks, the memory is leaking at the lines I malloc memories. I tried to free them outside of the loop like the following but the compiler wouldn't recognize p: `"error: 'p' undeclared (first use in this function)"`If I free them inside the while loop I will get a Segmentation fault. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have another `p` defined before the loop, that won't even compile!

Comment: You need to free payload first and it needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: Each time you call `malloc`, it's a new allocation. Each one must be individually freed. One `free` for every `malloc`. As @ShafikYaghmour says, you need `free(p->payload); free(p);` inside the loop, after your last `fwrite`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Like the error message says, you use a variable named `p` after the loop, but the only variable named `p` in your code exists only in the loop. This is solved by addressing the next problem.
2. You allocate multiple packets and payloads, but you one try to free one of each. The deallocation should be in the loop.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet *p = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
       p->payload = malloc(sizeof(nread+1));
       p->payload = buff;

       ...

       free(p);
       free(p->payload);
   }
   ```
3. You use `*p` after you free it. Your `free` calls are in the wrong order.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet *p = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
       p->payload = malloc(sizeof(nread+1));
       p->payload = buff;

       ...

       free(p->payload);
       free(p);
   }
   ```
4. You mean to allocate `nread+1` bytes, but you allocate `sizeof(nread+1)` bytes.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet *p = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
       p->payload = malloc(nread+1);
       p->payload = buff;

       ...

       free(p->payload);
       free(p);
   }
   ```
5. By the time you call `free(p->payload)` (were you to move it to the end of the loop), `p->payload` no longer contains a pointer to the buffer you allocated, so `free(p->payload)` tries to deallocate the wrong block. You need to use another variable to keep track of this block.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet *p = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
       char* payload = malloc(nread+1);
       p->payload = payload;
       p->payload = buff;

       ...

       free(payload);
       free(p);
   }
   ```
6. I'm pretty sure you meant to allocate `nread` bytes, not `nread+1`, since you probably meant to copy the bytes you read into the buffer.
7. You overwrite `p->payload` immediately after setting it. The memory allocation and subsequent deallocation of `p->payload` appears to be entirely useless.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet *p = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
       p->payload = buff;

       ...

       free(p);
   }
   ```
8. There's no reason to allocate and deallocate the same block of memory over and over again. In fact, there's no reason to use the heap at all.

   ```
   while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 256, infp)) > 0) {
       struct packet p;
       p.payload = buff;

       ...
   }
   ```
9. You write to handle a structure containing a pointer. That's very unlikely to be correct.
10. All the other fields of the structure are initialized. That's very unlikely to be correct.
11. You write `p->block_size` bytes of `p->payload` disk, but `p->payload`'s size is `nread`. (In fact, `p->block_size` is uninitialized memory.)
12. You never write to the handle the size of the payload (`nread`), making it impossible for code to read what you've written.

You haven't provided enough information to solve the last four problems.

---

I think you're trying to write length-prefixed blocks, where each length-prefix is one byte long and each

```
+---+----- ... -----+---+----- ... -----+---+----- ... -----+...
| i |    i bytes    | j |    j bytes    | k |    k bytes    |
+---+----- ... -----+---+----- ... -----+---+----- ... -----+...
```

If so, you want

```
while ((nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 255, infp)) > 0) {
    unsigned char len = (unsigned char)nread;
    fwrite(&len, 1, 1, outfp);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, nread, outfp);
}
```

Comment: Added to answer. I think that's all the problems.

Comment: holy moly you are awesome. Thanks a lot I will try to fix them

Comment: Are you trying to write length-prefixed blocks? See addition at the bottom.